# How to dynamically trigger a Window based on the number of processed elements?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an Apache Beam pipeline which runs on Google Cloud Dataflow. This a streaming pipeline which receives input messages from Google Cloud PubSub which are basically JSON arrays of elements to process.

Roughly speaking, the pipeline has these steps:

1. Deserializes the message into a `PCollecttion<List<T>>`.
2. Splits (or explodes) the array into a `PCollection<T>`.
3. Few processing steps: some elements will finish before other elements   and some elements are cached so they simply skip to the end without much processing at all.
4. Flatten all outputs and apply a `GroupByKey`(**this is the problem step**): it transforms the `PCollection` back into a `Pcollection<List<T>>` but it doesn't wait for all the elements.
5. Serialize to publish a PubSub Message.

I cannot get the last `GroupByKey` to group all elements that where received together. The published message doesn't contain the elements that had to be processed and took longer than those which skipped to the end.

I think this would be straight forward to solve if I could write a custom Data-Driven trigger. Or even if I could dynamically set the trigger `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast()` from a customized `WindowFn`.

It doesn't seem that I can make a custom trigger. But is it possible to somehow dynamically set the trigger for each window?

--

Here is a simplified version of the pipeline I am working on.

I have simplified the input from an array of objects `T` into a simple array of Integer. I have simulated the keys (or IDs) for these integers. Normally they would be part of the objects.

I also simplified the slow processing step (which really is several steps) into a sigle step with an artificial delay.

(complete example gist https://gist.github.com/naringas/bfc25bcf8e7aca69f74de719d75525f2 )

```
PCollection<String> queue = pipeline
    .apply("ReadQueue", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(topic))
    .apply(Window
        .<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(3))
        .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(2)))
        .discardingFiredPanes());

TupleTag<List<KV<Integer, Integer>>> tagDeserialized = new TupleTag<List<KV<Integer, Integer>>>() {};
TupleTag<Integer> tagDeserializeError = new TupleTag<Integer>() {};
PCollectionTuple imagesInputTuple = queue
    .apply("DeserializeJSON", ParDo.of(new DeserializingFn()).withOutputTags(tagDeserialized, TupleTagList.of(tagDeserializeError)));

/*  
This is where I think that I must adjust the custom window strategy, set the customized dynamic-trigger
*/
PCollection<KV<Integer, Integer>> images = imagesInputTuple.get(tagDeserialized)
    /* I have tried many things
    .apply(Window.<List<KV<Integer, Integer>>>into(new GlobalWindows()))
    */
    .apply("Flatten into timestamp", ParDo.of(new DoFn<List<KV<Integer, Integer>>, KV<Integer, Integer>>() {
        // Flatten and output into same ts
        // like Flatten.Iterables() but I set the output window
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(@Element List<KV<Integer, Integer>> input, OutputReceiver<KV<Integer, Integer>> out, @Timestamp Instant ts, BoundedWindow w, PaneInfo p) {
            Instant timestamp = w.maxTimestamp();
            for (KV<Integer, Integer> el : input) {
                out.outputWithTimestamp(el, timestamp);
            }
        }
    }))
    .apply(Window.<KV<Integer, Integer>>into(new GlobalWindows()));

TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>> tagProcess = new TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>>() {};
TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>> tagSkip = new TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>>() {};
PCollectionTuple preproc = images
    .apply("PreProcessingStep", ParDo.of(new SkipOrNotDoFn()).withOutputTags(tagProcess, TupleTagList.of(tagSkip)));

TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>> tagProcessed = new TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>>() {};
TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>> tagError = new TupleTag<KV<Integer, Integer>>() {};
PCollectionTuple processed = preproc.get(tagProcess)
    .apply("ProcessingStep", ParDo.of(new DummyDelasyDoFn).withOutputTags(tagProcessed, TupleTagList.of(tagError)));

/* Here, at the "end"
the elements get grouped back
first: join into a PcollectionList and flatten it
second: GroupByKey which should but doesn't way for all elements
lastly: serilize and publish (in this case just print out)
*/
PCollection end = PCollectionList.of(preproc.get(tagSkip)).and(processed.get(tagProcessed))
    .apply("FlattenUpsert", Flatten.pCollections())
    //
    .apply("GroupByParentId", GroupByKey.create())
    .apply("GroupedValues", Values.create())
    .apply("PublishSerialize", ParDo.of(
        new DoFn<Object, String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext pc) {
                String output = GSON.toJson(pc.element());
                LOG.info("DONE: {}", output);
                pc.output(output);
            }
        }));
// "send the string to pubsub" goes here
```

Comment: Can you look at adding an artificial key to a batch of records and then group by that in which case the group by key will wait for all the events with that id.

Comment: the `GroupByKey` already uses an id (defined by the input data).

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output data and the problem you are seeing ?

Comment: To summarize, you want in your rebuilt `Pcollection<List<T>>` (step 4) the same number of element that the first one, before the split (step 1)?

Comment: yes @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: For each `List<T>` can you not assign a unique id and then use a `Combine.perKey() ` for each of those ids and convert it back?

Comment: Can  you share more piece of code? How do you perform your split? What type of windows is used?

Comment: I have added a code sample. thanks

Comment: Maybe a timer-based approach could work in this case, applying a stateful DoFn after re-windowing into global windows. There is a nice example [here](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2019/06/11/looping-timers.html). Keep in mind that, for your use case, it would be better to use [processing time timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) (instead of event based) to allow for the maximum time it can take to process a single element accounting for retries, etc.

Comment: @GuillemXercavins but I don't want the pipeline to wait for a maximum time before emiting grouped ouput, in some cases all elements will skip processing.
It seems that the fact that the processing time for each element depends on the element (some might not need processing but still need to be part of the ouput) is not well aligned with BEAM's intended use cases?
The only possibility I see is custom triggers (which don't seem supported https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-101) or a customized window which does pretty much the same as the trigger (I don't know how I would do this)

Answer (score 4):

I played around a little bit with stateful pipelines. As you'd like to use data-driven triggers or `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast()` I assume you know the number of elements that conform the message (or, at least, it does not change per key) so I defined `NUM_ELEMENTS = 10` in my case.

The main idea of my approach is to keep track of the number of elements that I have seen so far for a particular key. Notice that I had to merge the `PreProcessingStep` and `ProcessingStep` into a single one for an accurate count. I understand this is just a simplified example so I don't know how that would translate to the real scenario.

In the stateful ParDo I defined two state variables, one `BagState` with all integers seen and a `ValueState` to count the number of errors:

```java
// A state bag holding all elements seen for that key
@StateId("elements_seen")
private final StateSpec<BagState<Integer>> elementSpec =
      StateSpecs.bag();

// A state cell holding error count
@StateId("errors")
private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> errorSpec =
      StateSpecs.value(VarIntCoder.of());
```

Then we process each element as usual but we don't output anything yet unless it's an error. In that case we update the error counter before emitting the element to the `tagError` side output:

```java
errors.write(firstNonNull(errors.read(), 0) + 1);
is_error = true;
output.get(tagError).output(input);
```

We update the count and, for successfully processed or skipped elements (i.e. `!is_error`), write the new observed element into the `BagState`:

```java
int count = firstNonNull(Iterables.size(state.read()), 0) + firstNonNull(errors.read(), 0);

if (!is_error) {
   state.add(input.getValue());
   count += 1;
}
```

Then, if the sum of successfully processed elements and errors is equal to `NUM_ELEMENTS` (we are simulating a data-driven trigger here), we flush all the items from the `BagState`:

```java
if (count >= NUM_ELEMENTS) {
   Iterable<Integer> all_elements = state.read();
   Integer key = input.getKey();

   for (Integer value : all_elements) {
      output.get(tagProcessed).output(KV.of(key, value));
   }
}
```

Note that here we can already group the values and emit just a single `KV<Integer, Iterable<Integer>>` instead. I just made a `for` loop instead to avoid changing other steps downstream.

With this, I publish a message such as:

```sh
gcloud pubsub topics publish streamdemo --message "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]"
```

And where before I got:

```java
INFO: DONE: [4,8]
```

Now I get:

```java
INFO: DONE: [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10]
```

Element `7` is not present as is the one that simulates errors.

Tested with `DirectRunner` and 2.16.0 SDK. Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/f3721b499fec7aaf71d69f90a33e6d98).

Let me know if that works for your use case, keep in mind that I only did some minor tests.

Comment: thanks, I am trying it out. There's just a couple of issues: the number of elements is dynamic but known at the moment of deserialization. So I will add the total to each element. 
and the tricky part is that processing must happen across several steps, so I will try to manually group by statefully (or maybe it'll have to be a combineFn).

Comment: Yes, for the first issue you can add it to the element. For example, embedding it into the key (`id#num_elements`) and then have a third state variable with the number of elements per key and window. The second one will depend on the full use case, of course, and might require more work to adapt.